# can you please tell the name of theme used in laravel official website?

Tags: laravel, themes

[image]

i just want to know that theme name used in laravel official website.
i just fell in love with this theme

Comment: i want a name of code editor theme

Comment: Hey did my answer work for you? If so do not forget to mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is also opensource:

[here is the repository for it](https://github.com/laravel/laravel.com)

It is probably using **TailwindCSS**

If you are asking for code theme then check tourchlight [here](https://torchlight.dev/docs/clients/laravel)

Comment: That syntax highlighting theme is most likely _not_ using Tailwind

Comment: OP asked for theme so I answered that specific question. However, I also added repository link and it show "torchlight". I linked that too. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

It is Torchlight if you are asking the code thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a [MATERIAL THEME UI](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8006-material-theme-ui), in addition to having the theme you uploaded the photo to, you will have many different themes that you can use.